# GMSCoordinateBounds returns all the markers instead of just visible markers

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am using  `GMSCoordinateBounds` to get a list of markers that are in visible area. But I am getting all the markers that are plotted instead of just visible ones.

This is how I am doing it:

```
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = [mapView_.projection visibleRegion];
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithRegion:visibleRegion];
GMSMarker *resultMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[markerArray count]; i++) //this has all the markers 
{
    resultMarker = [markerArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([bounds containsCoordinate:resultMarker.position])
    {
        NSLog(@"User is present on screen");
        [listTableArray addObject:resultMarker.title];
    }
}

[listTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: line 3. scratch the superfluous alloc/init there -- it is never even read

Comment: are you sure your marker array is fine? as well as the table :) the code looks ok

Comment: is projection correct at the time of calling?

Comment: How do I check if that projection will give me correct visible area?

Comment: check the coordinates of the visibleRegion

Comment: I also wanted the markers in the visible region of the map. Tried your code, and it works like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I'm pretty sure whatever your issue is, it's coming from somewhere other than the code you posted.

Another potential issue is that if your map allows rotation, all manner of disorienting stuff will happen to your `GMSVisibleRegion` object. (ie. the `farLeft` property won't correspond to the north-western point). I'd think `GMSCoordinateBounds` would take that into account and not get tripped by it.

Having said that, you can write your own method to check if a marker's coordinate is contained in a region. This is one that I've written (including my own "wrappers" for region and marker):

```
-(BOOL)isMarker:(SGMarker*)m inVisibleRegion:(SGRegion*)region
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D upperLeftPosition = region.topLeft;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerRightPosition = region.bottomRight;

    if (m.position.latitude > lowerRightPosition.latitude && m.position.latitude < upperLeftPosition.latitude &&
        m.position.longitude < lowerRightPosition.longitude && m.position.longitude > upperLeftPosition.longitude) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

// In my region wrapper, this is how I make sure I have the north-east/south-west points
+(SGRegion*)regionWithGMSVisibleRegion:(GMSVisibleRegion)region
{
    SGRegion* mapRegion = [[self alloc] init];

    // Since the camera can rotate, first we need to find the upper left and lower right positions of the
    // visible region, which may not correspond to the farLeft and nearRight points in GMSVisibleRegion.

    double latitudes[] = {region.farLeft.latitude, region.farRight.latitude, region.nearLeft.latitude};
    double longitudes[] = {region.nearRight.longitude, region.nearLeft.longitude, region.farLeft.longitude};

    double highestLatitude = latitudes[0], lowestLatitude = latitudes[0];
    double highestLongitude = longitudes[0], lowestLongitude = longitudes[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        if (latitudes[i] >= highestLatitude)
            highestLatitude = latitudes[i];
        if (latitudes[i] < lowestLatitude)
            lowestLatitude = latitudes[i];
        if (longitudes[i] >= highestLongitude)
            highestLongitude = longitudes[i];
        if (longitudes[i] < lowestLongitude)
            lowestLongitude = longitudes[i];
    }

    mapRegion.topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(highestLatitude, lowestLongitude);
    mapRegion.bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lowestLatitude, highestLongitude);

    return mapRegion;
}
```

So if you use these methods instead, you should be able to absolutely tell where your issue is coming from (ie. not from here ;) ).